# Excel-VBA Unite two logical statements

Tags: vba, excel

I think this is pretty common and I can't find it. I just don't know how to call this, but I basically want to make this:

```
Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x, 5).Value <> "Closed" or Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x, 5).Value <> "Resolved"
```

Condensed down to something like this:

```
Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x, 5).Value <> ("Closed" or "Resolved")
```

I made the top from what I know in other programs but I am not sure how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I think you have to do it the first way.

Comment: So you think there is no way to do this in a shorter way?

Comment: I do not know of a way put it that way. Is there a specific reason you need this shorter/

Comment: My logic line is much longer than I'd like it to be. I just think that there should be a way to do this as it is not very uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x, 5).Value = "Closed" Or Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x, 5).Value = "Resolved" Then
    MsgBox "Test Postivie"
Else
    MsgBox "Test Negative"
End If
```

or

```
Select Case Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x, 5).Value
    Case "Closed", "Resolved"
        MsgBox "Test Positive"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Test Negative"
End Select
```

Comment: I guess you could say this Case is "Closed"

Comment: Thank you for your response Jason. I am trying to keep it all in one line. I just find it a bit repetitive that I cannot do two conditions at the same time.

Any way to do that?

Comment: Any particular reason you're trying to keep it all on one line?  While it may take a little more space, it'll be more clear and understandable if you keep on separate lines.  If you simply want it all on the same line, you can enter `:` between each statement, `Select Case Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x,5).Value: Case "Closed", "Resolved": msgbox("Test Positive"): Case Else: msgbox("Test Negative"): End Select`

Comment: Thank you for your response Jason. I am trying to keep it all in one line. I just find it a bit repetitive that I cannot do two conditions at the same time. Any way to do that?  @ Jason_Walker

Comment: If InStr(1, "ClosedResolved", Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x, 5).Value) > 0 Then MsgBox "Positive Test" Else MsgBox "Negative Test"

Answer (score 0):

You may use some array functions to execute a lookup :

```
If IsError( Application.Match(Worksheets("JIRA EXPORT").Cells(x, 5).Value, _
Array("Closed", "Resolved"), False)) Then
    ' Concluding test code
Else
    ' Not concluding test code
End If
```